# Listview item to change text from page 1 to page 2

Tags: c#, windows, windows-phone-7

I am using Visual Studio 2012 (c# and XAML) and creating a Windows phone application

I have a listview on my page 1 which when clicked on i.e. listview item 1 when clicked an image appears.

This also happens with another item and what i want is for when they have clicked the value in the listview for them to be brought to another page when clicking on the picture that appeared where text is describing the picture that popped up in the first page

For example, in listview item 1 when clicked an image of Jk Rowling appears to the right and if the user clicks on that image they go to the second page (which is working fine) but when i click on the picture on the first page i want text to load into the textbox that i have created on the second page so the user sees a long description about that author. (So i want different text to appear depending on what listview item the user has chosen)

Below is my code

FIRST PAGE

```
public void AuthorList_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
if (AuthorList.SelectedIndex == 1)
{

BitmapImage Dostoyevsky = new BitmapImage(new Uri("dostoyevsky.jpg",UriKind.Relative));
AuthorImage.Source = Dostoyevsky;
AuthordescriptionText.Text = @"Born: 11 November 1821
Died: February 9 1881 of Epilepsy, Emphysema

Dostoyesky is one of the greats of Russian literature with novels such as Crime and Punishment, The Idiot
Demons and The Brothers Karamazov";


}
else if (AuthorList.SelectedIndex == 2)
{
BitmapImage Tolstoy = new BitmapImage(new Uri("tolstoy.jpg", UriKind.Relative));

AuthorImage.Source = Tolstoy;

AuthordescriptionText.Text = @"Born: 9 September 1828
Died: 20 November 1910 (Pneumonia)
Tolstoy is usually remembered as the man who created the masterpiece
War & Peace which is over 1000 pages, his other works include Anna karanina and his trilogy Childhood, boyhood
and youth which is based on his experiences in the Crimean war";


}

else if (AuthorList.SelectedIndex == 3)
{
BitmapImage Turgenev = new BitmapImage(new Uri("turgenev.jpg", UriKind.Relative));
AuthorImage.Source = Turgenev;


}

}

private void GoToAuthorPage(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{

}

public void ImageTapTodifferent(object sender, GestureEventArgs e)
{
if (AuthorList.SelectedIndex == 1)
{





}
NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/AuthorPage.xaml", UriKind.Relative));

}

private void UpdateImage(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
AuthordescriptionText.Opacity = 50;
}



protected override void OnNavigatedFrom(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
{

}

}
}
```

SECOND PAGE

```
private void BackButton(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{

NavigationService.GoBack();



}

private void OnTapAuthorPage(object sender, System.Windows.Input.GestureEventArgs e)
{



AuthorDescrptionLong.Text = @"

Quote: If you want to be happy, be.


}
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

After seeing your code i think you are not going the write way. But you will learn with experiance. So I suggest you to use MVVM Pattern for your application. Try to make a sample application that follow mvvm pattern and play with bindings.

So basically try `GalaSoft MVVM Toolkit` nuget package and install it. After that you should create two ViewModels(simplest way) for your two separate pages say `Page1ViewModel` and `Page2Viewmodel`.

For you simple usage made a string type property in `Page2ViewModel` that should be binded to your second page 'AuthorDescrptionLong.Text'.

Now you can use MessengerClass for communicating between Viewmodels.

I have mentioned a lot here.So read these links for guidance. It is time learn something new :)

- [**What is Mvvm Pattern**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/gg405484(v=pandp.40).aspx)
- [**MVVM Pattern Implementation in Windows phone 8**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/gg521153(v=vs.105).aspx)
- [**MVVM - good read**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj721615(v=vs.105).aspx)

I don't know this is an answer to your question but if you are developing for windows phone then learn what i have suggested.
Happy Learning :)